# how to send parameters to webmethod using jquery ajax using asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have Issue   how  to send parameters to webmethod using jquery ajax my script code bellow ITS NOT WORKING PLS SUGGEST ME...

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "View.aspx/Getgraph12",

        data: '{name12: "' + machineidnew + '" }',

        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            chartdatamain = data.d;
            drawchart();
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        }
    })
```

> View.aspx/Getgraph12

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<ChartDetails> Getgraph12(string name12)
{
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried using the query string instead? View.aspx/Getgraph12/name12=foo since you're only doing a GET I don't know if using the data approach is quite correct.

Comment: when am using public static List<ChartDetails> Getgraph12(string name12) list its not working when am using string its working

Comment: remove the dataType json see it works?

Comment: secondly why you are using get method? ... withe get method use query strings see it works?

Comment: Don't try creating your own json manually. What you are sending is not valid json

Comment: thank you its working, just i used post method  and i removed json .. thank you bro